# How to run papermill on a remote server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, papermill, nteract

I want to run a `papermill` Python script to execute a `.ipynb` file. As of now, it runs on local but I want to run it on another server, say another Docker container.

I tried reading the documentation(https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/test-papermill/latest/test-papermill.pdf) but it states how to create a new engine, nothing about how to make remote connections and define their kernels.

Comment: What kernel are you wanting to use in the notebook? Python?

Comment: I ask because if you are using Spark or Pyspark, there is some additional kernel information you need to provide if you are doing this through the spark magic. Also, posting your `kernel.json` files would help give us a better idea on how to help you.

Comment: normal Python3 kernel

Comment: As long as jupyter and papermill are installed in your other environment, or built in your docker image, a standard python kernel should work "out of the box" with papermill. You will need to post more information about the code you're executing and the errors you're getting.

Comment: Here you have an script to run papermill in a remote machine: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/blob/master/dlvm/tools/scripts/notebook_executor.sh Instructions here: https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/gcp-notebook-executor-v0-1-2-8e37abd6fae1

Comment: @AviralSrivastava I am facing the same issue, were you able to accomplish this? thanks!